# WP_Query issues with argument posts_per_page

Tags: wp-query, theme-development

I have a query that displays the names of donors as well as a dedication. It displays using a date meta query.

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'donors',
   'order_by' => 'id',
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'date_query' => array(
     array(
       'after' => $from,
       'before' => $to
     ),
     'inclusive' => true,
   ),
   'meta_query' => array(
     array(
       'key' => 'type',
       'value' => 'donor',
       'compare' => '='
     )
   )
 );
```

I would like for this to display in an unlimited manner, but for some reason it only displays 252 items when it should display 378. Is there an exhaust limit for how many queries I can do?

**EDIT**

Here is my complete code of my custom query

```
$colors = array('#00274E', '#a33038', '#6391B5');
$separators = array();
$sepcount = 0;
$sepindex = 0;

$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'arcf_donors',
        'order_by' => 'id',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'is_paged' => true,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                  'key' => 'type',
                  'value' => 'donor',
                  'compare' => '='
                )
        )
);

$subquery = new WP_Query($args);

$separators = array(
        'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/445_4387134.jpg',
        'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/564_3765091.jpg',
        'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/829_4027101.jpg',
        'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/988_4172711.jpg',
        'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/987_4120232.jpg',
        'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/127_3764954.jpg',
        'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/440_4241356resized.jpg',
        'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/127_3764954.jpg',
        'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/311_2996427.jpg',
        'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/445_4387134.jpg'
);

<?php if ( $subquery->have_posts() ):
        while ( $subquery->have_posts() ): $subquery->the_post();
                $color = $colors[mt_rand(0,2)]; $sepcount++; ?>
                <?php if ($sepcount == 5): ?>
                        <?php $sepindex++; ?>
                        <?php if ($sepindex > 9) $sepindex = 0;?>

                        <div id="post-290" class="<?php print $sepindex; ?> post-size-1x1 project type-project status-publish format-link hentry post-single has_thumb about about experiments experiments portfolio portfolio services services team team post" data-post-size="1x1">
                                <div class="inner-image-placeholder" id="post-290-in" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $separators[$sepindex]; ?>');">
                                        <div class="image-link-inner"></div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                <?php $sepcount = 0; ?>

              <?php else: ?>

                <div id="post" class=" post-size-<?php the_field('brick_size'); ?> project type-project status-publish format-standard hentry has_thumb portfolio portfolio post" data-post-size="<?php the_field('brick_size'); ?>" style="background-color:<?php echo $color; ?>">
                  <div class="post-wrapper inner-image-placeholder">

                    <!-- Begin Title Section -->
                    <div class="image-link-inner">
                      <?php
                      echo '<p class="donor">';
                      echo the_title();
                      echo '</p>';
                      if ($show == 'dedication'):
                        if (get_field('brick_message') != '' ||  get_field('block_message') != ''):
                          echo '<div class="image-post-overlay" style="display: block;"><div class="image-post-overlay-in">';
                          if (get_field('brick_size') == '1x1'):
                            echo '<p>'. the_field('brick_message') .'</p>';
                          else:
                            echo '<p>'. the_field('block_message') .'</p>';
                          endif;
                          echo '</div></div>';
                        endif;
                      endif;
                      ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Begin Dedication Section -->
                    <?php if (get_field('brick_message') != '' ||  get_field('block_message') != ''): ?>
                      <div class="image-post-overlay">
                        <div class="image-post-overlay-in">
                          <?php
                          if ($show == 'name'):
                            if (get_field('brick_size') == '1x1'):
                              echo '<p>'. the_field('brick_message') .'</p>';
                            else:
                              echo '<p>'. the_field('block_message') .'</p>';
                            endif;
                          else:
                            echo the_title();
                          endif;
                          ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                  </div>
                </div>

              <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: 378 posts are they all published post? Also try using a big number like 500 and see it pull all 378 posts. That way we know the problem is from the `posts_per_page` key.

Comment: I've tried using a big number like three hundred and it still only displays 252 posts

Comment: I'm still trying to formulate and articulate the problem I'm having. When I run the whole thing through xdebug in php storm the query is showing the correct number of posts. Somehow when this displays to the page it's a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
'post_type' => 'any', 
'post_stauts' => 'any',
```

to your arguments and see what happens. This should retrieve posts in all post types with any post status. If it only retrieves 252 posts, then the other posts doesn't not meet your criteria in your query.

The other important thing is that with such an amount of posts, you might exceed the maximum execution time to retrieve these posts, but this will result in an error.

You should also set your debug to true in wp-config.php, and check this way if any error is returned. Check out [**Debugging Wordpress**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

**EDIT**

Your problem is quite actually simple and expected behavior. When running a custom query and directly after that run another custom query, or even using main query, it is expected that the first query will break the second query if you do not **reset** the custom query.

It is of utmost importance that any custom query made with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) that you reset the postdata first before running another query. This is done with [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

> Use this function to restore the global $post variable of the main query loop after a secondary query loop using new `WP_Query`. It restores the `$post` variable to the current post in the main query.

To solve your issue, simply add `wp_reset_postdata();` just before the last `endif;`

Comment: I turned this debugging feature on and addressed any of the errors left on the page with the search form, and tried adding these parameters to my arguments but it didn't work, I'm wondering if I need to maybe use an archive page to display these posts? I will try to talk to the person that originally created the theme.

Comment: Creating an archive page will not solve your problem. I can only think that only 252 posts falls within the criteria of your custom query. That is all I can think of. One final thing, download and install qeury monitor and refresh the page. Check that the 30 s maximum time is not exceeded.

Comment: Okay so I realized what was happening and it's kind of weird. Here's a paste of my full markup http://pastebin.com/rzTbpmq0. The separator loop is interfering with the main posts loop in my markup. So when it runs, it counts the number of separators and adds it to the post count. So on a page like this, I *should* have 317 posts, but instead I have 254 actual posts and 63 separator items

Comment: This does not work for me, thank you for updating my question

Comment: What happens if you remove everything inside your loop and just return `the_title`. Also, do a var dump. add this in your template and see what ouput do you get `echo $GLOBALS['subquery']->request;`

Comment: Okay I fixed it in a different way, by taking out the `else` where the posts are being displayed and just put: `endif; wp_reset_postdata();` which I guess took the separators out of the main query. Thanks so much for helping me work through this problem!

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for letting me know. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score -2):

Please try with `wp_reset_query();` after your query.
like:

```
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: This won't help, as it creates a new instance of WP_Query.